# R: Extracting elements between characters in a web page

Tags: html, regex, r, web-scraping

I have two lines of info from a web page that I want to parse into a data.frame.

> `[104] "  &#x0024;1775 / 2br - 1112ft&sup2; - Wonderful two bedroom two bathroom with balcony! (14001 NE 183rd Street  )"`
>
> `[269] "            var pID = \"4619136687\";"`

I'd like it to look like this.

> `postID    |rent|type|size|description             |location`
>
> `4619136687|1775|2br |1112|Wonderful two bedroom...|14001 NE 183rd Street`

I was able to use the `sub()` command to get the ID but I'm not exactly familiar with regex in the `sub()` command to parse out what I need when there are spaces, such as in line `[104]`.

> `sub(".*pID = \"(.*)\";.*","\\1", "            var pID = \"4619136687\";")`

Any help would be wonderful, Thanks!

Comment: Use `strsplit` rather than `sub` for that

Comment: For you second string I guess you could just do `gsub("[^[[:digit:]]", "", "            var pID = \"4619136687\";", perl = T)`